# Recompile with -fPIC issue

Tags: c, assembly

I have following c program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("hello');
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this file

```
gcc -c rr2.c
```

and then use linker with *shared* option like

```
/ld-new -shared    -o tmpdir/dump rr2.o
```

It gives the following error

> rr2.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I don't understand why this error occurs. Can anyone help me to understand actually why this error is appearing?

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic shared "objects" do not have fixed addresses they are loaded into memory. That means all references to function and variables have to be *position independent*. You have to create *Position Independent Code* (or PIC for short).

This is done, as suggested by the linker, by adding the `-fPIC` flag when compiling:

```
> gcc -fPIC -c rr2.c
```

Comment: I am now confused with relocatable and position independent code.

Comment: Usually it means that the code may be run from different addresses and it contains special tables with data what has to amended in the code to make it run. The latter is something which can placed at any any address and run  without the need of any changes

Comment: @GauravPathak Code can be relocatable without being position-independent. Code that isn't position-independent might need to be modified before it can run. That modification can have some interesting (bad) effects on virtual memory usage, so more modern operating systems tend to require PIC for shared objects.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Comment: @GauravPathak in the question the string literal `"hello"` is stored in memory (probably in `.rodata` section) and the linker puts it somewhere in the executable and build relocation table for the OS, so OS will load the executable to some memory, and patch the code to let it know, where the `"hello"` landed. In PIC-like code the machine code is produced in "relative" way, that it knows the literal is for example +300 bytes off the current instruction, so it doesn't need absolute address from OS, it will simply use it's current address of instruction (`cs:rip`) plus the relative offset.